# PHP File Downloads instead of Running

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have seen the other similar questions but my httpd_config is read only and making a new copy and adding in the suggested lines doesn't work. i even put the file in the same directory as my .html file and .php file.
Here is my code for the .html the form is in bold:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>




<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>Online Food Orderer</h1>
</header>
  
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ra46/Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ra46/NewOrder.html">New Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ra46/PreviousOrders.html">Previous Orders</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ra46/Account.html">Account</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ra46/AddRestaurant.html">Add Restaurant</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<article>
  <h1>Previous Orders</h1>
<body>
*<form action="php.php" method = "post">
<table>
<tr>
<td> Customer Number </td>
<td> <input type = "text" name="customer_number"
  size="5" /> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<p> <input type ="submit" value="submit" />  </p>
   </form>*
</body>


</article>

   
<footer>Assignment 2</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP file which doesn't run at all:

```html
<?php
$db = mysql_connect(string server= ini_get("mysql.default_host"),
string username= =ini_get("mysql.default_user"),
string password= =ini_get("mysql.default_password"))
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');
sql.safe_mode boolean


?>
<HTML>
 <head>
</head>
<body>




<h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die ('Error querying database.');

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query );
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row['firstName'].' '.$row['lastName'].': '.$row['email'] .'<br />';
}
mysqli_close($db);
?>


</body>
</HTML>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your http server delivers php files in code for download instead of interpreting them you need to modify your configuration. If that configuration  file is "read only", then you have to change that.

Comment: i don't have permission to change it and since this is the library i fear that i may damage it for everyone (which is probably why its read-only)

Comment: Then it looks as if you are trying to use a feature that is not actually installed / configured? Nothing in the world you can do in that case. Except maybe ask the one responsible for that http server.

Comment: maybe its something to do with where my php code is? its in the same folder as it so i'd assume that it would work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with where your scripts are, _unless_ that http server has a _very_ strange configuration. What makes you believe that this server actually does support php? Your description suggests it does _not_.

Comment: You are also using `mysql_connect` instead of `mysqli_connect` at the very top of your file and then further on you are using `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` in your while loop, which will also be causing some errors.  You should also be using prepared statements and validating your inputs to prevent mysql injection.  You can read more about prepared statements with mysqli [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You have few issues in your PHP codding. Even with the errors the PHP should run and should display at-least the error messages. First of all check wether PHP is installed and configured(in Apache config) in your sever.

Comment: what is your server environment. Lamp Wamp or anything else.